# Swipe up to close bootstrap mobile navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hello im working on one website with Bootstrap framework v3.3.4. 
When I click to toggle button the mobile navbar are open and i want to slideup to close navigation.

[this is an image description of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBR0H.jpg)

Is it possible?

Comment: you can use jquery property slideup on click above button

Comment: What do you mean? You want it to animate differently when sliding up, or you just want it to close after clicking a link. Also, post your code. The default nav already does slide up when closing: http://www.codeply.com/go/n74aBY6DDt.

Comment: when I slideup the opened mobile navigation to close only with slide up gesture

Comment: Ah, now I see what you looking for. You mean swipe up.

Comment: yea i mean swipe up

Answer (score -2, accepted):

here is the answer of the question

First of all we need to link touch.js into your header

```
<script src="./js/touch.js"></script>
```

---

touch.js

```
var supportTouch = $.support.touch,
        scrollEvent = "touchmove scroll",
        touchStartEvent = supportTouch ? "touchstart" : "mousedown",
        touchStopEvent = supportTouch ? "touchend" : "mouseup",
        touchMoveEvent = supportTouch ? "touchmove" : "mousemove";
$.event.special.swipeupdown = {
    setup: function() {
        var thisObject = this;
        var $this = $(thisObject);
        $this.bind(touchStartEvent, function(event) {
            var data = event.originalEvent.touches ?
                    event.originalEvent.touches[ 0 ] :
                    event,
                    start = {
                        time: (new Date).getTime(),
                        coords: [ data.pageX, data.pageY ],
                        origin: $(event.target)
                    },
                    stop;

            function moveHandler(event) {
                if (!start) {
                    return;
                }
                var data = event.originalEvent.touches ?
                        event.originalEvent.touches[ 0 ] :
                        event;
                stop = {
                    time: (new Date).getTime(),
                    coords: [ data.pageX, data.pageY ]
                };

                // prevent scrolling
                if (Math.abs(start.coords[1] - stop.coords[1]) > 10) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }
            $this
                    .bind(touchMoveEvent, moveHandler)
                    .one(touchStopEvent, function(event) {
                $this.unbind(touchMoveEvent, moveHandler);
                if (start && stop) {
                    if (stop.time - start.time < 1000 &&
                            Math.abs(start.coords[1] - stop.coords[1]) > 30 &&
                            Math.abs(start.coords[0] - stop.coords[0]) < 75) {
                        start.origin
                                .trigger("swipeupdown")
                                .trigger(start.coords[1] > stop.coords[1] ? "swipeup" : "swipedown");
                    }
                }
                start = stop = undefined;
            });
        });
    }
};
$.each({
    swipedown: "swipeupdown",
    swipeup: "swipeupdown"
}, function(event, sourceEvent){
    $.event.special[event] = {
        setup: function(){
            $(this).bind(sourceEvent, $.noop);
        }
    };
});
```

After that we need to place the bootstrap nav into div with id="nav" like that:

```
<div id="nav">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
here is you navigation
</nav>
</div>
```

And you can activate the swipeup closing of bootstrap mobile navigation with this script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#nav').on('swipeup',function(){
    $('#menubtn').click();
} ); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to collapse the navbar on scroll by adding the class navbar-shrink. I have used #Nav as an id for nav just for an example and adjust the offset according to your page.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($("#Nav").offset().top > 100) {
        $("#Nav").addClass("shrink");
    } else {
        $("#Nav").removeClass("shrink");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery for that like below

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>slideUp demo</title>
 <style>
   div {
   background: #3d9a44;
    margin: 3px;
     width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
   float: left;
   }
  </style>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>

   Click me!
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
       <div></div>
     <div></div>

 <script>
  $( document.body ).click(function() {
     if ( $( "div:first" ).is( ":hidden" ) ) {
       $( "div" ).show( "slow" );
      } else {
          $( "div" ).slideUp();
      }
   });
 </script>

</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a mobile touch (gestures) lib such as https://github.com/benmajor/jQuery-Touch-Events and then just hook it up to the navbar...

```
// enable swipe up to close nav on mobile
$('#mN').bind('swipeup', function(e, touch) {
    $('[data-toggle="collapse"]').trigger('click');
});
```

[Demo on Codeply](http://www.codeply.com/go/n74aBY6DDt/swipe-to-close-mobile)